# How to build exe with Adobe AIR adt on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: apache-flex, ubuntu, air, air-native-extension

I have an existing application that is built on Ubuntu Linux using Maven. It has a server part (Java), Client part (Flex/AIR) and installers (Windows installers + RPMs). The client part now needs to be expanded to use a Native Extension. For this, you cannot longer build a `.air`, it needs to be a `.exe`.

I am trying to figure out how I can build this .exe now on Ubuntu Linux.

I am directly calling the adt.jar with some arguments to try to do this, but I get the following error:

```
Native extensions are not allowed for the current target
```

Is there a way to make this work?

regards,

Wim

Comment: You can only build exe's on Windows.  I don't think "Captive Runtime" or "Native Extensions" were added until after Linux support for AIR stopped.

Comment: AFAIK, building `.air` files that use native extensions is supported.

Comment: @nwellnhof can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. AIR apps that use ANEs cannot be packaged as `.air` files.